# Difference between sending leads into Dev account as opposed to Sandbox account? Leads not sent into Sandbox with similar settings as Dev account

Tags: sandbox, leads, developer-console, logging, debug-logs

We have created a webapp to send Leads into the salesforce system, which works great in our Dev account. However when using the same app for another business, which has a Sandbox account, the Leads are not saved.

I walked through all their settings and they are almost identical. Only differnece is my contact there has no "Reset my security token" under personal settings, however I don't think that is needed (it's not active on my end), we have whitelisted the App IPs.

The access log shows a succesful connect with the salesforce system, but nothing else.

Two Questions:

1. Is there an essential difference in functionality between a developer account, and a real account with a sandbox, which makes our lead generation system not enter their leads?
2. Is there any other way to view logs? Can we see if there is a reason why entering a lead is denied/failing?

As a dev it is a bit hard to pinpoint the reason for this when I cannot read a log :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an essential difference in functionality between a developer account, and a real account with a sandbox, which makes our lead generation system not enter their leads?

The most likely scenario is a login issue. A Dev/Prod org uses login.salesforce.com, and sandboxes use test.salesforce.com. But without logs or errors from the webapp, no way to tell for sure. That's the only major technical difference. There are other possibilities, like triggers, validation rules, etc, but you should at least start with the basics.

> Is there any other way to view logs? Can we see if there is a reason why entering a lead is denied/failing?

You can set up debug logs (Setup > Monitoring > Debug Logs), but that presumes that you're not dealing with a login issue (as above). If you don't get any logs, the problem is a login issue. If you do, then debug logs would show you more information about the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it does not seem to be a login issue, since the logs show the correct App user login which is marked as "success". It's just not adding the leads to the client sandbox account, no error on our webapp level either.

We did notice we (Devlevel) have a tab called Marketing > Leads, whereas their account does not have a Marketing option in their system, but a Sales > Leads. I think these "Leads" sections are the same though. FYI: We used this package to build our app on https://github.com/bjsmasth/php-salesforce-rest-api